# Xamarin forms: Problem with permissions: READ_SMS & WRITE_SMS

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a little problem. I had in my app the permissions on SEND_SMS WRITE_SMS. When Google announced the changes in the guidelines, I immediately adjusted my manifest and updated the app. In the Playstore the permissions are not displayed so I thought that everything worked. However, my app was removed from the Playstore a few weeks ago. So I wanted to ask if anyone had a similar problem.
I've tried that too: uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" tools:node="remove"
Thanks for any help

My manifest looks like:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: What are you asking for?

Comment: If somebody knows how I can fix this an update my app again :)

Comment: What do you use WRITE_SMS for? You can still use SEND_SMS if you ask for the permission using the marshmallow permission API.

Comment: I don't even use it. I just thought maybe we will use it later on but we came to the conlusion to not use it

Comment: Just remove it from your manifest then?

Comment: That's what I did. I updated the app and in the playstore the permission ist not longer listed but google removed the app because they think I have it in my manifest..

Comment: When you build, check the generated manifest whether it still contains the permission. Maybe one of your dependencies is adding it? Also using `tools:node="remove"` doesn't remove it.

Comment: I don't know if this was the right manifest but I updated my post and you can see these permissions are not used

Comment: You can usually find the generated manifest in the obj/Android folder after building. Something else might be adding that permission. Are you using a 3rd party library that adds it?

Comment: Sorry it took me some time to build but I have checked there is no read sms nor write sms

Comment: Warning message in the google play console is cached and is not accurate after an app's permissions are updated. It's cached for a day or two and then it goes away.

Comment: In my case the message was gone for a short time but then the app was completely removed from the playstore

Comment: any Update @Markus3D? are you able to re-upload your app? if yes, can you give me some light? =)

Comment: @RyanMotal I was able to upload my app again but without the two permissions :/